# How can i press the Save button repeatedly , but only save once data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When i have to press save button repeatedly it will save same data many time.

`@click="save"`

```
 methods:{

        save(){

            }
         }
    }
```

I want when i click save button repeatedly only one data can be save
to database.

How can i do? :)

Comment: The simplest way would be to disable the button on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try

@click="debounce(save, 500);"

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
    let timer;

    return function(...args) {
        const context = this;

        clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
    };
}
```